# base controller not found laravel php

Tags: php, database, laravel, classnotfound

```
<?php namespace vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Facades;

use DB;
use BaseController;

class ModuleController extends BaseController{
    public function index()
    {
        //Display data from students table.
        $data=DB::connection('mysql')->select('select * from students');
    }
}
```

Error message:Fatal error: Class 'BaseController' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\test.php on line 6

Comment: What's with that namespace?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Laravel 4 Can't find BaseController from namespaced controller](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18687464/laravel-4-cant-find-basecontroller-from-namespaced-controller)

Comment: @CarissaSamaroo if you're happy with my answer below, accept it :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to change

`use BaseController;`

to

`use Illuminate\Routing\Controller as BaseController;`

<s>Also, you'll have an error with `DB`. You need to use</s>

`use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;`

instead of

`use DB;`

also namespace :)

`namespace App\Http\Controllers;`

instead of

`namespace vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Facades;`

Try to learn some OOP basics before using Laravel.

Comment: `use DB;` is totally fine. The facade has an alias in the global namespace.

Comment: I am new to Laravel and I've been following tutorials. I've done everything that you've said and now I'm getting the following error: Fatal error: Class 'Illuminate\Routing\Controller' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\config\test.php on line 6

Answer (score 1):

You can let artisan create each and every controller for you, like:

```
$ sudo php artisan make:controller ModuleController
```

and he takes care of everything.
You can see all services artisan can provide to you with:

```
$ sudo php artisan
```